# Android: ShowDialog with Variables

Tags: java, android, variables, showdialog

Hi I'w working into a ShowDialog and I want it to show a message with 2 local variables. For that reason It says there is an error so I would appreciate some help if there is a way of showing these variables. Here is my code and the line where the error is is this one:

```
  .setMessage("The NIF is" +user +DNIWord  "-")
```

The rest of the code is this one:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id){


     switch (id) {
     case DIALOG_ERROR_CANDIDATO:
           return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
               .setTitle(R.string.error)
               .setMessage("The NIF is" +user +DNIWord  "-")
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
               })

               .create();
     }

    return null;


}
```

The 2 variables are obtained from here:

```
int user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString());

public static String DNIWord(int user) {
  return String.valueOf(user) + NIF_STRING_ASOCIATION.charAt(user % 23);
}
```

Thank you

Edit:

```
 package com.prueba.inicio;


import com.prueba.R;
import com.prueba.R.drawable;
import com.prueba.R.id;
import com.prueba.R.layout;
import com.prueba.R.string;
import com.prueba.inicio.Autorizacion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.style.BackgroundColorSpan;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;



public class Ident extends Activity {
    private static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CANDIDATO= 0;
    public static final String NIF_STRING_ASOCIATION = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";


    public static String DNIWord(int user) {
      return String.valueOf(user) + NIF_STRING_ASOCIATION.charAt(user % 23);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
       {
          super.onCreate(icicle);
          setContentView(R.layout.identificacion);
          Button bSiguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_siguiente);
          final EditText dniText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dni_candidato);

    bSiguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

         int user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString());


         String longitud = dniText.getText().toString();


         if(user==8){
             Intent i = new Intent(Ident.this,Autorizacion.class);
                 startActivity(i);
         }
         else{
             showDialog(DIALOG_ERROR_CANDIDATO);
         }


    }


});

}
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id){

         switch (id) {
         case DIALOG_ERROR_CANDIDATO:
               return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                   .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error)
                   .setTitle(R.string.error)
                   .setMessage("The NIF is" +user +DNIWord (user)+  "-")
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        }
                   })

                   .create();
         }

        return null;


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a class variable, `DNIWord` is *just* a method. Modify the call so it is like this:

```
.setMessage("The NIF is" +user +DNIWord (user)+  "-")
```

DNIWord though works with a shadowed `user` variable, so

```
("The NIF is" +user +DNIWord (user)+  "-")
```

could be shortened to just

```
("The NIF is" + DNIWord (user)+  "-")
```

<s>However, since `user` seems to be class-scoped and you try to get the value of `dniText`, which seems to be an `EditText/TextView`, it is *very likely* that you will also get a `NullPointerException` when you actually run your app. Move the assignment of user to somewhere like inside 
`onCreateDialog()`.</s>

**Edit:** `user` is not class scoped but instead local to `onCreate()` local variables, like the name implies are local to the enclosing method.

Move user outside `onCreate()` then take out the `int` user in onCreate and write it just as `user`.

```
int user = 0; //class instance variable
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{

  //...
  try{
    user = Integer.parseInt(dniText.getText().toString()); //no "int", just user
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
  }
}
```

Then in your `onCreateDialog()` method, you should be able to access `user`.

Comment: Thank you A--C but the error reamains the same. I've edited the info with the whole class.

Comment: @Katherine99 in that case tell us exactly what the error says. **Edit** your scopes are off. User is local to `onCreate()`